# How do I expand all rows in this table on the website?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Forgive me if I sound like a total novice, but I've been banging my head trying to understand how I can make all rows expand together rather than manually clicking each row and expanding on this website.

I am sure there is some way to modify the code and make it happen altogether.

Can someone please help me with the process?

Attaching the [website link](https://www.rupeevest.com/Mutual-Fund-Debt-Holdings/100010)
Here type in any company - let's say HDFC.
[image]

Once you click, you see many rows, but all have to be expanded manually.

Please help me make it happen altogether with a change in the code. It will be very helpful for my learning, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace or add this additional code in your footer code snippet and it will work, it would take some time to expand all rows depends on data. I have edited your own code to give you a quick resolution. Just edit the code according to your need, it is just an overview for your own code.

```js
$(".exp_det").each(function() {
          
   scheme_code = parseInt(this.parentElement.parentElement.id);
  var index=0;
           // {
               // old_table = $("#details").html();
               table_reg=""
               $("#details").each(function()
               { 
                  for(var i=0;i<this.children.length;i++)
                   {
                      
                     if( parseInt(this.children[i].id)==scheme_code  )
                     { 
                         // debugger;
                        if(!this.children[i].classList.contains("dtl_opn"))
                        {
                           table_reg+="<tr id='"+this.children[i].id+"' class='dtl_opn'>"+$(this.children[i]).html().replace(/icon-plus-squared-alt/g,'icon-minus-squared-alt')+"</tr>"+hash[this.children[i].id]  
                           
                             // console.log("details Open");
                           // $(this.children[i].firstElementChild.children[0].children[0]).removeClass("icon-plus-squared-alt");
                           
                           //  $(this.children[i].firstElementChild.children[0].children[0]).addClass("icon-minus-squared-alt");
                             

                            // debugger;
                           dtls_open.push(this.children[i].id)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                                           
                            index = dtls_open.indexOf(this.children[i].id);
                            if(index!=-1)
                            {
                               dtls_open.splice(index,1);

                               // console.log("details Close");
                                // alert("coming here");
                                // $(this.children[i].firstElementChild.children[0].children[0]).removeClass("fa icon-minus-squared-alt").addClass("icon-plus-squared-alt");
                               table_reg+='<tr id="'+this.children[i].id+'">'+this.children[i].innerHTML.replace(/icon-minus-squared-alt/g,'icon-plus-squared-alt');+'</tr>';   
                            }
                            

                        }
                        
                     }
                     else
                     {  

                          // $("#dtls_"+scheme_code).remove();

                          if(this.children[i].id!="dtls_"+scheme_code)
                          {
                            console.log("In ELSE");

                            var index = dtls_open.indexOf(this.children[i].id);
                            if(index!=-1)
                            {
                               table_reg+='<tr id="'+this.children[i].id+'" class = "dtl_opn">'+this.children[i].innerHTML+'</tr>';  
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              table_reg+='<tr id="'+this.children[i].id+'">'+this.children[i].innerHTML+'</tr>';  
                            }

                               
                          }
                          
                     }
                        
                   }

               }) 

               $("#details").html(table_reg);
               $("#details").addClass("class_show");
           // }

});
```